# Loading a flat file into SQL Server 2008 R2 via BizTalk 2010

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, biztalk, biztalk-2010, flat-file

I am trying to find my way around BizTalk 2010.  The scenario is simple: I need to take a flat file (delimited, positional, segmented etc...) and load it into a table in SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am trying to do this with a WCF-SQL adapter.

At this point I do not care for speed (i.e., it does not matter if there will be multiple inserts or one bulk insert, but in the long run I would like to be able to do a bulk insert), I just want to get something working.

I have the following done so far:

1. `TestTable1` in table in SQL Server 2008 R2
2. `InsertIntoTestTable` stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2
3. Visual Studio Project with (a) a schema for the incoming Flat File, (b) Generated Schema for the SQL table, (c) a Map from the incoming flat file schema to the SQL file schema and (d) a pipeline to disassemble the flat file.

I have deployed this project to BizTalk and created a receive port for the flat file specifying the receive folder and inbound map.  When I drop a test file into the receive folder, it disappears but TestTable1 is not loaded with any values.

What am I missing? Where does BizTalk place the test file? How can I set this up?

I have looked over a number of tutorials (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/gg153515, https://sandroaspbiztalkblog.wordpress.com/2012/08/20/biztalk-server-transform-text-files-flat-files-into-xml-a-practical-example-part-3/, ) but just don't understand what I am missing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

So I got it to work.  Not sure how yet, but I tweaked the adapter settings and changed the value of Quantity in the input file from 1.000 to 1.  I also now able to write to an xml file.  The error that I was getting is as follows looks like it was having problems with "Quantity" data type:

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "ToSQL" with URL "mssql://.//TestDB?". It will be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send Port. Details:"Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.XmlReaderParsingException: The input data for the field/parameter "Quantity" is invalid according to the expected SqlDbType Int. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>      at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>      at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
>      at Microsoft.Adapters.Sql.MetadataHelper.ConvertXmlValueToDotNetObject(String xmlString, String fieldParameterName, SqlDbType sqlDbType, Int32 maxLength, Int32 precision)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace: 
>      at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)".

Comment: How have you got the send port configured?  Can you see any suspended messages in BizTalk Administration Console?

Comment: I am attempting to configure the send port right now.  But no success.  I was able to configure it to output a file to a "SEND" folder, but I cannot make it load the DB.  I receive the following error

Comment: The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port "ToSQL" with URL "mssql://.//TestDB?".   The port is configured as follows: Type: WCF-Custom, URI mssql://.//TestDB? (not sure about this), Send handler: BizTalkServerApplication, Send pipeline: PassThruTransmit, Action: TypedProcedure/dbo/InsertIntoTestTable (not sure about this), Binding: sqlBinding

Comment: I would suggest you create a file send port to write the message in a file first. If you can do that. post your file content.

Comment: Need the full error/warning you're getting when it fails to transmit.  This could be due to any number of problems: bad adapter config, bad DB config, bad file content.

Comment: The error clearly indicates the problem "The input data for the field/parameter "Quantity" is invalid according to the expected SqlDbType Int" Check what is in that field being sent to the database, if it is not an integer e.g. a blank, than that is your issue

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error:
   Quantity" is invalid according to the expected SqlDbType Int.

'1.000' is not a valid int type.
you should convert it to a valid format such as "1"